# silverstripe static publisher - pages affected by DataObject Changes

Tags: caching, content-management-system, silverstripe

is there a possibility to trigger an update of the cache if a DataObject is edited?
for example updating a News DataObject should update the cache of pages, that are displaying these NewsObjects.

many thanx,
Florian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I could do using the [StaticPublishQueue](https://github.com/silverstripe-labs/silverstripe-staticpublishqueue) module. In your NewsDataObject.php:

```
function onAfterWrite() {
    parent::onAfterWrite();

    $url = array();
    $pages = $this->Pages(); //has_many link to pages that include this DataObject
    foreach($pages as $page) {
        $pagesAffected = $page->pagesAffected();
        if ($pagesAffected && count($pagesAffected) > 0) {
            $urls = array_merge((array)$urls, (array)$pagesAffected);
        }
    }
    URLArrayObject::add_urls($urls);
}
```

This takes each of the pages that references your DataObject, asks it for all it's URL and the URL of any related pages (e.g. Virtual Pages that reference that page), compiles all the URLs into a big array, then adds that array to the static publishing queue. The queue will gradually process until all the affected pages are republished.

The event system allows you to add a layer of abstraction between the republishing and the triggers for republishing, but for something simple you don't necessarily need to use it. Instead, you can add pages to the queue directly. (You might also like to read this [blog post describing the StaticPublishQueue module](http://www.silverstripe.org/introducing-the-static-publish-queue-module/))

Answer (score 0):

The [StaticPublisherQueue](http://addons.silverstripe.org/add-ons/silverstripe/staticpublishqueue) module will handle that for you.

Comment: thx! do you understand the readme? for example I can´t see how to create a implementator of MyEventListener. the readme says to add the function Object#MyEvent(Event $event). But where and what is the exact syntax?

I added this to config.php:
StaticPagesQueueEvent::register_event('NewsUpdateEvent', 'NewsUpdateEventListener');

and that to News DataObject:
public function onAfterWrite() {
        parent::onAfterWrite();
        StaticPagesQueueEvent::fire_event(new NewsUpdateEvent($this));
    }

with the rest I´m still in the dark. Do you know any further? thx!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else comes across this, and doesn't wish to use the StaticPublishQueue module instead of StaticPublisher, it does appear to be possible in StaticPublisher, the following works for me:

```
function onAfterWrite() {
    parent::onAfterWrite();

    $urls = array();

    $pages = Page::get();
    foreach($pages as $page) {
        $urls[] = $page->Link();
    }

    $sp = new FilesystemPublisher();
    $sp->publishPages($urls);
}
```

Note the last 2 lines, and use the Page::get to specify the exact pages that need to be updated.